# Php : How to disable/enable a list , based on a checkbox selection

Tags: php

How to enable/disable a list based on checkbox selection in PHP. I have to enable the list present in the form, only when the check box is selected.I couldn't find how to do this in PHP. If anyone can help.

I want to disable this list as I select the checkbox.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function enable_text(status)
{
status=!status; 
    document.f1.other_text.disabled = status;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload=enable_text(false);>

<form name=f1 method=post>
<input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" >
<select name="Colors">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="R">Red</option>
<option value="G">Green</option>
<option value="B">Blue</option>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your code here....

Comment: Add your code here what you had tried?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried. It will be easy for the further explanations.

Comment: @Gyandeep Sharma : Added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  $('#d-checkbox').click(function(e) {
                if($(this).prop('checked') == true)$('#color').removeAttr("disabled");
                else $('#color').attr("disabled","disabled");
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name=f1 method=post>
            <input type="checkbox" id="d-checkbox">
            <select name="Colors" id="color"  disabled="disabled">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="R">Red</option>
                <option value="G">Green</option>
                <option value="B">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <script>
            $('#d-checkbox').click(function(e) {
                if($(this).prop('checked') == true)$('#color').attr("disabled","disabled");
                else $('#color').removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is your solution...

Comment: Thanks @Gyandeep Sharma! One quick question,I think  I was not clear in the beginning I wanted the list to disabled when page loads and when we click the check box it gets enable. For that I made the changes in the code you have given  `<script>
            $('#d-checkbox').click(function(e) {
                if($(this).prop('checked') == true)$('#color').removeAttr("disabled");
                else $('#color').attr("enabled","enabled");;
            });
        </script>`  but after it gets enabled its not getting disable even if I uncheck the check box.

Comment: Thanks @Gyandeep Sharma ! it helped a lot.

Answer (score -2):

```js
  $('#d-checkbox').click(function(e) {
                if($(this).prop('checked') == false)$('#color').attr("disabled","disabled");
                else $('#color').removeAttr("disabled");
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name=f1 method=post>
            <input type="checkbox" id="d-checkbox">
            <select name="Colors" id="color">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <option value="R">Red</option>
                <option value="G">Green</option>
                <option value="B">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <script>
            $('#d-checkbox').click(function(e) {
                if($(this).prop('checked') == false)$('#color').attr("disabled","disabled");
                else $('#color').removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```